# Publishing Service Field Changes Only Revision Being Returned

Tags: publishing-service

I'm having some trouble getting info from the pipeline for the new-ish Sitecore Publishing Service in Sitecore 8.2.

We're getting the list of ModifiedFields from PublishEndResultBatchArgs. The problem is only the revision field is being returned. We are expecting a list of what was changed. See code. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
public class PublishBatchResultProcessor
{
    public void Process(PublishEndResultBatchArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var result in args.Batch)
        {
            var fieldChanges = result.Metadata.FieldChanges;
            //This gives me a collection with only one item - The revision field
        }
    }
}
```

Patch File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <publishEndResultBatch>
        <processor type="Foo.PipelineStuff.PublishBatchResultProcessor, Foo.PipelineStuff"
                   patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Pipelines.BulkPublishingEnd.RaiseRemoteEvents, Sitecore.Publishing.Service']" />
      </publishEndResultBatch>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did you try lastPublishedDate vs item's publish date. ? i have tried this before for getting items which were modified since last publish.

Comment: This question applies to the Publishing Service module. Not the out of the box Sitecore publishing.

Answer (score 6):

This is by design.  For performance reasons, the Publishing Service only reports field changes that are essential for features in Sitecore to function correctly.

The fields that will be reported on are:

- Revision - {8CDC337E-A112-42FB-BBB4-4143751E123F}
- NeverPublish - {9135200A-5626-4DD8-AB9D-D665B8C11748}
- PublishDate - {86FE4F77-4D9A-4EC3-9ED9-263D03BD1965}
- UnpublishDate - {7EAD6FD6-6CF1-4ACA-AC6B-B200E7BAFE88}
- PublishingTargets - {74484BDF-7C86-463C-B49F-7B73B9AFC965}
- HideVersion - {B8F42732-9CB8-478D-AE95-07E25345FB0F}
- ValidFrom - {C8F93AFE-BFD4-4E8F-9C61-152559854661}
- ValidTo - {4C346442-E859-4EFD-89B2-44AEDF467D21}
- WorkflowState - {3E431DE1-525E-47A3-B6B0-1CCBEC3A8C98}
- DefaultWorkflow - {CA9B9F52-4FB0-4F87-A79F-24DEA62CDA65}
- Clones.SourceVariant - {1B86697D-60CA-4D80-83FB-7555A2E6CE1C}
- Clones.SourceItem - {19B597D3-2EDD-4AE2-AEFE-4A94C7F10E31}

The ability to configure the Service to report on other fields will be delivered in v2.0 Update 1, due for release probably sometime in May 2017.

Comment: So we tried it and it does not seem to work. This is what shows up in the showconfig.aspx. Is there something else we need to look at to get the values? <Publishing patch:source="z-PublishService.config">
  <Services>
    <RequiredPublishFieldsResolver>
      <Options>
        <AdditionalItemFieldsIds>
          <f1>{4712EF95-FAD6-4250-BB4E-D9094079D431}</f1>
        </AdditionalItemFieldsIds>
      </Options>
    </RequiredPublishFieldsResolver>
  </Services>
</Publishing>

Comment: @RReilley  Apologies, I wasn't clear.  This needs to go into the config of the Service itself, not the Sitecore module side.  I will amend my answer to make this clear.

Comment: So we've been trying this solution but not having any luck. We put in a support ticket because that lets us put up a lot more information about our environment but they seem kinda confused about the whole thing. Do you have any ideas for why this isn't working?

Comment: @RReilley Assuming you're on V2 of Publishing, I can't say without investigating properly. One of our team will be much better placed to give you an accurate answer, I should have a chance early next week to take a look. Sorry it can't be sooner.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor I appreciate the help. We currently have a ticket open.